# How to restrict a network port to be used by VM but not host computer?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

Want to know if it is possible to assign a network port on my server to only be accessed by the VM on that server. This would mean the host computer would not be able to use it to access that network resources.

Configuration:

- Port 1: LAN A
- Port 2: DISABLED
- Port 3: DISABLED
- Port 4: LAN B (VM Access Port)

Is this possible and if so how can it be done. The server would need be able to access LAN A but not LAN B. Only the VM would access LAN B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the network in Hyper-V virtual switch manager, just uncheck the box that says "Allow the management operating system to share this network adapter".

Comment: That is correct. Keep in mind that you cannot change that setting after you create a vSwitch, so in case you already created one, you'll need to delete and recreate it.

Comment: Dominik, while you can't do that through the Hyper-V Manager, you can do it through PowerShell after the fact.